# Preserve user folder location on browse for image?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I am using the Ajax File Upload, and I am trying to make it so that when the user browses for an image, the next time they go to browse for an image they end up in the same folder.  In other words, if I pick an image from FolderA, next time I go to pick an image I start in FolderA.  I am not sure if this is something I would implement on the server side or on the client side, or both.

```
<div class="upload-photos-add" id="Q0012_00" runat="server">
    <asp:AjaxFileUpload EnableViewState="false" ID="AjaxFileUpload2" ContextKeys="0012.00" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload_UploadComplete" OnClientUploadComplete="onClientUploadComplete" OnClientUploadCompleteAll="onClientUploadCompleteAll" OnClientUploadStart="onClientUploadStart"></asp:AjaxFileUpload>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the default path in your web.config as below:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UploadPath" value="../UploadFiles/"/>
</appSettings>
```

and for each time you select a new path try to update the value attribute in  as below:

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
string oldValue = config.AppSettings.Settings["value"].Value;
config.AppSettings.Settings["value"].Value = "New Path";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```